# how to move only EFI partition from HDD to SSD without losing any boot entries from EFI partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I want to move only my EFI partition,leaving other partition untouched.Since my windows bootmanager and grub2 (boot entry of ubuntu) both resides in EFI partition I cannot move it using minitool partition or gparted.Please guide

This is how I checked my boot entries:

`mkdir /mnt/sda1`

`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1/`

`ls /mnt/sda1/EFI/`

> *Boot grub2win Microsoft ubuntu*

As shown in the image HDD- `/dev/sda`,SSD- `/dev/nvme0n1`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried booting a GParted live disk/usb? Your EFI partition is locked so GParted cannot do anything to it as things stand. However you may find that you only need to unmount it. It’s only mounted when running normally so that any updates to the kernel can be applied

Comment: ok I will try and let you know

Comment: unable to move to SSD,Only I'm able to move it within HDD

Comment: Did you make space for it on the SSD? You need unallocated space to move it to. This article is old but describes the process well. https://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/03/copy-partitions-with-gparted/

Comment: Thanks,It worked by using live CD that means when I was not using Any OS which basically booted through EFI partion that's why I wasn't able to move it earlier.

Comment: Will summarise this so that others can more easily find the answer. If you are happy please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried booting a GParted live disk/usb? Your EFI partition is locked so GParted cannot do anything to it as things stand. GParted is also available on the Ubuntu install media if you boot into a live session by choosing "Try Ubuntu"

You will need unallocated space on the destination SSD to move your efi partition into. You can create this with GParted by making the large partition slightly smaller.

Comment: I found out a tool called **MiniTool Partition Wizard**,
using this one can mount and view files inside the partition, change the size of the Partition and also move the EFI partition to the desired location.